# three.js - Help adding pinch zoom to css3d_youtube demo - trackball controls messing up camera position

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, three.js

I'm trying to sell my boss on using three.js to create a CSS3D interface integrated with video providers (like YouTube). One of the requirements is showing it on a mobile device - I've chosen an iPad since the Android tablet is quirky.

Since my demo is scheduled for this Thursday I thought the quickest thing to do was to show him the wonderful css3d_youtube demo.

The problem is it is not configured to use gestures (touch pinch zoom) and I'm having a hard time doing this.

I also needed to add a few things like a background image and the ability to have the YouTube player go full screen so I had to take the original code and modify it.  I saw the periodic table is so I decided to use the TrackBall controller in my code. You can see my modified code [here](https://bitbucket.org/attlabs/att_html5_uverse_poc/raw/2d6938912839bbcfabdb2c78dfcd204edf05d966/public/javascripts/libs/you_tube_grid.js)

The trackball controller seems to shift the camera's y position.  You can see the actual page I created [here if you view in a tablet](http://morning-thicket-1335.herokuapp.com/#/search). I used the Modernizr library to recognize if the device is touch screen so you wont see it just by using a desktop browser.

If it would be more helpful I can remove that condition so it can be seen in a desktop browser.

If I remove the code that is messing up the camera position (you can see where I do this my searching for Modernizr.touch in the code) the camera is no longer centered to the video  poster image when clicking on the button.

I also tried just regular JavaScript gesture events by adding this function:

```
function onPinch(e) {
  move(e.scale)
}
```

and calling it in an event handler:

```
`document.body.addEventListener('gestureend', onPinch, false)`
```

but that was a disaster.  The CSS3D objects rendered very slowly.

Can someone help me add pinch zoom functionality to the css3d youtube demo? Or at least offer some advice on how to proceed?  I wasn't able to find anything to help via Google -ing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like TrackballControls.js [has been updated to support touch zoom gestures](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1822).

If any one else is having this problem, just [get the latest version](https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js).

The CSS3D [periodic table](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) and [youtube](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_youtube.html#cats) examples seem to have been updated too.